# Talend - Stats and Logs - On database - error

Tags: talend

I have a job that inserts data from sql server to mysql. I have set the project settings as -

Have checked the check box for - Use statistics(tStatCatcher), Use logs (tLogcatcher), Use volumentrics (tflowmetercatcher)

Have selected 'On Databases'. And put in the table names 
(stats_table,logs_table,flowmeter_table) as well. These tables were created before. The schema of these tables were determined using tcreatetable component.
The problem is when I run the job, data is inserted in the stats_table but not in flowmeter_table

My job is as follows

tmssInput -->tmap --> tmysqoutput.

I have not included tstatcatcher,tlogcatcher,tflowmetercatcher. The stats and logs for this job are taken from the project settings.
My question - Why is there no data entered in flowmeter_table? Should I include  tStatCatcher , tlogcatcher and tflowmetercatcher  explicitly in the job for it to run fine?

I am using TOS

Thanks in advance
Rathi

Comment: I have not worked using `tflowmetercatcher`, but in order to implement `tstatcatcher` and `tlogcatcher`, you need to use those components explicitly in jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using flow meter requires you to manually configure the flows you want to monitor.

On every flow you want to monitor, right-click on the row >parameters>advanced settings>Monitor connection.
Then you should be able to see data in your flow table.

If you are using the project settings , you don't need to add the *Catcher component on your job.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok, I get that I still need to use the components. If I use the components and then use the database output components to write the stats and logs to database, why must I enable them in project settings('use Database')?

Comment: No, you don't need to use the components in the job IF you define in your project settings that you are using the 3 catchers as a Global Project Settings. Nevertheless, you have to configure your flows (orange arrows) in your jobs to configure the Flow Meter part.

Comment: Ok, so I do not add tstatcatcher and tlogcatcher, but need to add and configure the tflowmetercatcher. I guess I must add tflowmeter too, right?

Comment: No, tFlowMeterCatcher is NOT needed neither. And you don't have to use tFlowmeter. Just rlight click on orange links to go to the parameters screen and click on monitoring checkboxes. I have added screenshots.

Comment: Thank you Corentin. I get it now

Answer (score 0):

You need to use tstatcatcher,tlogcatcher,tflowmetercatcher composant in the job directly.

The composant have already their schema defined so you jusneed to put a tmap and redirect in the table you want like :

[image]

Moreover in order tu use the tlog catcher you need to put some tdie or twarn in your job.

Comment: Using the components is not needed if you use the project settings (that is what OP did)